# Traversing through all the available paths in a diagraph

Tags: python-3.x, algorithm, dictionary, graph, graph-algorithm

There is a graph structure with numbers like below.

[image]

To load this structure in a graph object in python. I have made it as a multi line string as below.

```
myString='''1
2 3
4 5 6
7 8 9 10
11 12 13 14 15'''
```

Representing it as a list of lists.

```
>>> listofLists=[ list(map(int,elements.split())) for elements in myString.strip().split("\n")]
>>> print(listofLists)
[[1], [2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9, 10], [11, 12, 13, 14, 15]]
```

creating a graph structure using the below Node and edge class in python

Node Class, it requires position as a tuple and a value
Example: elements and its position , value

```
1 --- position (0,0) and value is 1
2 --- position (1,0) and value is 2
3 --- position (1,1) and value is 3
```

The node class

```
class node(object):
    def __init__(self,position,value):
        '''
        position : gives the position of the node wrt to the test string as a tuple
        value    : gives the value of the node
        '''
        self.value=value
        self.position=position

    def getPosition(self):
        return self.position

    def getvalue(self):
        return self.value

    def __str__(self):
        return 'P:'+str(self.position)+' V:'+str(self.value)
```

The edge class creates an edge between two nodes.

```
class edge(object):
    def __init__(self,src,dest):
        '''src and dest are nodes'''
        self.src = src
        self.dest = dest

    def getSource(self):
        return self.src

    def getDestination(self):
        return self.dest
    #return the destination nodes value as the weight
    def getWeight(self):
        return self.dest.getvalue()

    def __str__(self):
        return (self.src.getPosition(),)+'->'+(self.dest.getPosition(),)
```

The Directed graph class is as below. The graph structure is build as a dict adjacency list.
{node1:[node2,node3],node2:[node3,node4]......}

```
class Diagraph(object):

    '''the edges is a dict mapping node to a list of its destination'''
    def __init__(self):
        self.edges = {}

    '''Adds the given node as a key to the dict named edges ''' 
    def addNode(self,node):
        if node in self.edges:
            raise ValueError('Duplicate node')
        else:
            self.edges[node]=[]

    '''addEdge accepts and edge class object checks if source and destination node are present in the graph '''     
    def addEdge(self,edge):
        src = edge.getSource()
        dest = edge.getDestination()
        if not (src in self.edges and dest in self.edges):
            raise ValueError('Node not in graph')
        self.edges[src].append(dest)

    '''getChildrenof returns  all the children of the node'''   
    def getChildrenof(self,node):
        return self.edges[node]

    '''to check whether a node is present in the graph or not'''    
    def hasNode(self,node):
        return node in self.edges

    '''rootNode returns the root node i.e node at position (0,0)''' 
    def rootNode(self):
        for  keys in self.edges:
            return keys if keys.getPosition()==(0,0) else 'No Root node for this graph'
```

A function to create and return the graph object on which to work.

```
def createmygraph(testString):
    '''input is a multi-line string'''

    #create a list of lists from the string
    listofLists=[ list(map(int,elements.split())) for elements in testString.strip().split("\n")]
    y = Diagraph()
    nodeList = []

    # create all the nodes and store it in a list nodeList
    for i in range(len(listofLists)):
        for j in range(len(listofLists)):
            if i<=j:
                mynode=node((j,i),listofLists[j][i])
                nodeList.append(mynode)
                y.addNode(mynode)

    # create all the edges
    for srcNode in nodeList:
    # iterate through all the nodes again and form a logic add the edges
        for destNode in nodeList:
            #to add the immediate down node eg : add 7 (1,0) to 3 (0,0) , add 2 (2,0) to 7 (1,0)
            if srcNode.getPosition()[0]==destNode.getPosition()[0]-1 and srcNode.getPosition()[1]==destNode.getPosition()[1]-1:
                y.addEdge(edge(srcNode,destNode))
            #to add the bottom right node eg :add 4 (1,1) to 3 (0,0) 
            if srcNode.getPosition()[0]==destNode.getPosition()[0]-1 and srcNode.getPosition()[1]==destNode.getPosition()[1]:
                y.addEdge(edge(srcNode,destNode))

    return y
```

How to list all the paths that are available between two nodes.Specifically between **1---->11 , 1---->12 , 1---->13 , 1---->14 , 1---->15**
 I tried for a left first depth first approach for this case. But it failing to get the paths.

```
def leftFirstDepthFirst(graph,start,end,path,valueSum):
    #add input start node to the path
    path=path+[start]
    #add the value to the valueSum variable
    valueSum+=start.getvalue()
    print('Current Path ',printPath(path))
    print('The sum is ',valueSum)
    # return if start and end node matches.
    if start==end:
        print('returning as start and end have matched')
        return path

    #if there are no further destination nodes, move up a node in the path and remove the current element from the path list.
    if not graph.getChildrenof(start):
        path.pop()
        valueSum=valueSum-start.getvalue()
        return leftFirstDepthFirst(graph,graph.getChildrenof(path[-1])[1],end,path,valueSum)
    else:
        for aNode in graph.getChildrenof(start):
            return leftFirstDepthFirst(graph,aNode,end,path,valueSum)
    print('no further path to explore')
```

Testing the code.

```
#creating a graph object with given string
y=createmygraph(myString)
```

function to return terminal nodes like 11,12,13,14,15.

```
def fetchTerminalNode(graph,position):
    terminalNode=[]
    for keys in graph.edges:
        if not graph.edges[keys]:
            terminalNode.append(keys)
    return terminalNode[position]
```

Running the depth first left first function.

```
source=y.rootNode() # element at position (0,0)
destination=fetchTerminalNode(y,1) #ie. number 12
print('Path from ',start ,'to ',destination)
xyz=leftFirstDepthFirst(y,source,destination,[],0)
```

The path is fetched for the elements 11 and 12 but not for 13 or 14 or 15. i.e `destination=fetchTerminalNode(y,2)` does not work.Can please anyone suggest a way to approach this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PFB the function that I could come up with that uses the [breathfirstSearch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breadth-first_search) to print all the availble paths between the root node and the end nodes.

Google [Colab/github](https://github.com/rainu1729/data-analysis/blob/master/euler_project_graph.ipynb) link

```
def breathfirstalgo(graph,tempPaths,finalPath):
## iterates over all the lists inside the tempPaths and checks if there are child nodes to its last node.
condList=[graph.getChildrenof(apartList[-1]) for apartList in tempPaths if graph.getChildrenof(apartList[-1])]

tempL=[]    
if condList:

    for partialList in tempPaths:
        #get the children of the last element of partialList
        allchild=graph.getChildrenof(partialList[-1])

        if allchild:
            noOfChild=len(allchild)
            #create noOfChild copies of the partialList
            newlist=[partialList[:] for _ in range(noOfChild)]      
            #append the a child element to the new list
            for i in range(noOfChild):
                newlist[i].append(allchild[i])

            #append each list to the temp list tempL
            for alist in newlist:
                tempL.append(alist)

        else:
            pass

    #after completion of the for loop i.e iterate through 1 level
    return breathfirstalgo(graph,tempL,finalPath)
else:
    #append all the lists from tempPaths to finalPath that will be returned
    for completePath in tempPaths:
        finalPath.append(completePath)
    return finalPath
```

Testing the breathfirstsearch solution as below.

```
mygraph=createmygraph(myString)
print('The graph object is ',mygraph)
print('The root node is ',mygraph.rootNode())
#print(mygraph)
all_list=breathfirstalgo(mygraph,tempPaths=[[mygraph.rootNode()]],finalPath=[])

print('alllist is ')
for idx,partlist in enumerate(all_list):
    print(printPath(partlist))
```

The output is as below after modifying the `__str__` of node class as `str(self.value)`

```
The graph object is  <__main__.Diagraph object at 0x7f08e5a3d128>
The root node is  1
alllist is 
-->1-->2-->4-->7-->11
-->1-->2-->4-->7-->12
-->1-->2-->4-->8-->12
-->1-->2-->4-->8-->13
-->1-->2-->5-->8-->12
-->1-->2-->5-->8-->13
-->1-->2-->5-->9-->13
-->1-->2-->5-->9-->14
-->1-->3-->5-->8-->12
-->1-->3-->5-->8-->13
-->1-->3-->5-->9-->13
-->1-->3-->5-->9-->14
-->1-->3-->6-->9-->13
-->1-->3-->6-->9-->14
-->1-->3-->6-->10-->14
-->1-->3-->6-->10-->15
```

Answer (score 4):

Given a `tree`

```
tree = \
  [ [1]
  , [2, 3]
  , [4, 5, 6]
  , [7, 8, 9, 10]
  , [11, 12, 13, 14, 15]
  ]
```

And a `traverse` function

```
def traverse (tree):
  def loop (path, t = None, *rest):
    if not rest:
      for x in t:
        yield path + [x]
    else:
      for x in t:
        yield from loop (path + [x], *rest)
  return loop ([], *tree)
```

Traverse all paths...

```
for path in traverse (tree):
  print (path)

# [ 1, 2, 4, 7, 11 ]
# [ 1, 2, 4, 7, 12 ]
# [ 1, 2, 4, 7, 13 ]
# [ 1, 2, 4, 7, 14 ]
# [ 1, 2, 4, 7, 15 ]
# [ 1, 2, 4, 8, 11 ]
# [ 1, 2, 4, 8, 12 ]
# ...
# [ 1, 3, 6, 9, 15 ]
# [ 1, 3, 6, 10, 11 ]
# [ 1, 3, 6, 10, 12 ]
# [ 1, 3, 6, 10, 13 ]
# [ 1, 3, 6, 10, 14 ]
# [ 1, 3, 6, 10, 15 ]
```

Or collect all of the paths in a list

```
print (list (traverse (tree)))
# [ [ 1, 2, 4, 7, 11 ]
# , [ 1, 2, 4, 7, 12 ]
# , [ 1, 2, 4, 7, 13 ]
# , [ 1, 2, 4, 7, 14 ]
# , [ 1, 2, 4, 7, 15 ]
# , [ 1, 2, 4, 8, 11 ]
# , [ 1, 2, 4, 8, 12 ]
# , ...
# , [ 1, 3, 6, 9, 15 ]
# , [ 1, 3, 6, 10, 11 ]
# , [ 1, 3, 6, 10, 12 ]
# , [ 1, 3, 6, 10, 13 ]
# , [ 1, 3, 6, 10, 14 ]
# , [ 1, 3, 6, 10, 15 ]
# ]
```

Above, we used generators which are a high-level feature in Python. Maybe you wish to understand how to implement a solution using more primitive features...

The generic mechanism we're looking for here is the list monad, which captures the idea of ambiguous computation; some procedure that can return potentially *more than one* value.

Python already provides lists and a way to construct them using `[]`. We only need to supply the binding operation, named `flat_map` below

```
def flat_map (f, xs):
  return [ y for x in xs for y in f (x) ]

def traverse (tree):
  def loop (path, t = None, *rest):
    if not rest:
      return map (lambda x: path + [x], t)
    else:
      return flat_map (lambda x: loop (path + [x], *rest), t)
  return loop ([], *tree)

print (traverse (tree))
# [ [ 1, 2, 4, 7, 11 ]
# , [ 1, 2, 4, 7, 12 ]
# , [ 1, 2, 4, 7, 13 ]
# , ... same output as above ...
# ]
```

Oh and Python has a built-in [`product`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.product) function which happens to work exactly as we need. The only difference is that the paths will be output as tuples `()` instead of lists `[]`

```
from itertools import product

tree = \
  [ [1]
  , [2, 3]
  , [4, 5, 6]
  , [7, 8, 9, 10]
  , [11, 12, 13, 14, 15]
  ]

for path in product (*tree):
  print (path)

# (1, 2, 4, 7, 11)
# (1, 2, 4, 7, 12)
# (1, 2, 4, 7, 13)
# (1, 2, 4, 7, 14)
# (1, 2, 4, 7, 15)
# ... same output as above ...
```

In your program you attempt to abstract this mechanism through various classes, `node` and `edge` and `diagraph`. Ultimately you can structure your program however you want, but know that it doesn't *need* to be more complex than we have written it here.

---

Update

As [@user3386109](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50703780/traversing-through-all-the-available-paths-in-a-diagraph/50704146#comment88419460_50704146) points out in the comments, my program above generates paths as if each parent was connected to *all* children. This is a mistake however as your graph shows that parents are only connected to *adjacent* children. We can fix this with a modification to our program – changes below in **bold**

```
def traverse (tree):
  def loop (path, i, t = None, *rest):
    if not rest:
      for (j,x) in enumerate (t):
        if i == j or i + 1 == j:
          yield path + [x]
    else:
      for (j,x) in enumerate (t):
        if i == j or i + 1 == j:
          yield from loop (path + [x], j, *rest)
  return loop ([], 0, *tree)
```

Above we use an indices `i` and `j` to determine which nodes are "adjacent" but it cluttered up our `loop` a bunch. Plus the new code looks like it introduces some duplication. Giving this intention a name `adjacencies` keeps our function cleaner

```
def traverse (tree):
  def adjacencies (t, i):
    for (j, x) in enumerate (t):
      if i == j or i + 1 == j:
        yield (j, x)

  def loop (path, i, t = None, *rest):
    if not rest:
      for (_, x) in adjacencies (t, i):
        yield path + [x]
    else:
      for (j, x) in adjacencies (t, i):
        yield from loop (path + [x], j, *rest)

  return loop ([], 0, *tree)
```

Using it is the same, but this time we get the output specified in the original question

```
for path in traverse (tree):
  print (path)

# [1, 2, 4, 7, 11]
# [1, 2, 4, 7, 12]
# [1, 2, 4, 8, 12]
# [1, 2, 4, 8, 13]
# [1, 2, 5, 8, 12]
# [1, 2, 5, 8, 13]
# [1, 2, 5, 9, 13]
# [1, 2, 5, 9, 14]
# [1, 3, 5, 8, 12]
# [1, 3, 5, 8, 13]
# [1, 3, 5, 9, 13]
# [1, 3, 5, 9, 14]
# [1, 3, 6, 9, 13]
# [1, 3, 6, 9, 14]
# [1, 3, 6, 10, 14]
# [1, 3, 6, 10, 15]
```

The reason this simple `adjancies` function works is because your input data is uniform and valid. You can visualize the indices `i` and `i + 1` clearly by color-coding the paths in your image. We never have to worry about an index-out-of-bounds error because you can see `i + 1` is never computed on nodes without children (ie, the last row). If you were to specify *invalid* data, `traverse` does not guarantee a valid result.

[image: paths as indices]

Comment: Every output in this answer contains the line `1, 2, 4, 7, 13`. From the image at the top of the question, that's not possible, since 7 does not have an edge to 13.

Comment: I seem to have overlooked this detail! I core of the idea is the same, but a change would be needed to bind only adjacent children instead of all children. I'll revisit this later if I can find the time.

Comment: @user3386109 I made an update to address your comment :D

Comment: Thank you for the detailed explanation, the above code provides all the possible paths from start node 1 to the end nodes 11,12,13,14,15. However I was looking for an answer that will use the graph theory to answer the question.I agree to the point that `but know that it doesn't need to be more complex than we have written it here.` I am taking the edx course 6.00.2x that has graph algos, though I could apply it here. If you could suggest a way to approach this problem using graphs that would be helpful.